# C++ new followed by class

Tags: c++, class, syntax, semantics

A friend and I are working on an ancient C++ codebase. In this code, an array of CDelayEvent pointers is defined as follows

```
class CDelayEvent* m_pDelayEventList[DEF_MAXDELAYEVENTS];
```

and various objects in it are allocated in the following way

```
m_pDelayEventList[i] = new class CDelayEvent;
```

My question here is the use of the keyword `class` in both lines. The code compiles both lines with and without it.

1. Is this valid C++? It compiles, but we have never seen this before.
2. What does the `class` keyword do in this context?
3. Is it safe/better to remove it everyhwere? Does it change anything at all?

I could not find anything about this problem because searching for "new class" only finds unrelated articles and questions.

Comment: It's optional and can be omitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know C? Then you know how a structure is used? And that you need to use the `struct` keyword when e.g. declaring a variable of the structure?

In C++ structures and classes are really the same, and C++ made the need for the `struct` and `class` keywords *optional* so a structure or a class could be used as a type.

So in your case you can use `class CDelayEvent` or just `CDelayEvent`, they are semantically the same.

Comment: I do know C but using typedef to call `struct mystruct` by the name of `mystruct` has often been considered bad practice - I would have never guessed that the C++ standard bakes this behaviour into the language for classes.

Comment: @Kenji It's "baked in" for both classes and structures because they are considered types.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Is this valid C++? It compiles, but we have never seen this before.

Yes. It's optional to use it.

> 2. What does the class keyword do in this context?

Nothing special.

> 3. Is it safe/better to remove it everyhwere? Does it change anything at all?

Yes it is safe to remove it. That won't change anything.